# How to make php artisan tinker display full error(messages)s?

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to make an request to foreign API in tinker. As the response is a long error, it only shows the beginning of the error, like that:

> Client error: `POST https://foreign.api/w00t` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.32 - Error reportH1 {font-family:Taho (truncated...)

And that's all. Is there a way I could make tinker return the whole response?

Answer (score 7):

You can try these commands inside tinker:

```
wtf
```

These versions adds verbose:

```
wtf ?
wtf ?!?
wtf ?!?!?
```

Or this with complete message version:

```
wtf -a
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

`php artisan tinker --verbose`

Comment: Good guess, but it didn't change anything :(